# SMTP Content-Transfer-Encoding for html emails

Tags: email, smtp, smtpclient

Is there any reason why a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of `quoted-printable` would be screwing up a link, when sent from a SMTP server?

**Example:**

After setting the `mail from`, `rcpt to` and entering `data` mode, send this (emails removed):

```
From: Me <me@me.com>
To: You <you@you.com>
Subject: Email Test
Mime-Version: 1.0;
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable;

<html>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the email source is somehow getting screwed up and the a tag is changed to `<a href=3D"ttps://www.google.com/&quot;">Google</a>` (missing `h` from `https`).

If I change the Encoding to be `7bit` then everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that happens to come across this post - the issue was a simple one but not one that was immediately obvious to begin with.

When using `quoted-printable` you have to make sure you're passing properly encoded data. I was not. I was passing normal HTML through, thinking that was ok.

So in my example, the `<a>` tag would have to be encoded to `<a href=3D"https://www.google.com/">Google</a>` then it works.

I was trying to implement this using Go, so below is a function that will implement this functionality...

```
// Returns a properly quoted-printable string
func toQuotedPrintable(s *string) error {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := quotedprintable.NewWriter(&b)

    _, err := w.Write([]byte(*s))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while decoding to quoted-printable", err)
        return err
    }

    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while decoding to quoted-printable", err)
        return err
    }

    *s = b.String()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I think I'm having this same problem. I'm using a lambda function to send html using Amazon SES. Would you recommend that I encode the raw html for quoted-printable, or that I should use a different encoding?